# List of functions calls in python tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have an object

```
class Obj:
    def method1(self):
        print 'method1'

    def method2(self):
        print 'method2'

    def method3(self):
        print 'method3'
```

and function

```
def do_something():
    obj = Obj()
    obj.method2()
    obj.method1()
    obj.method3()
```

And I want to write test which tests do_something and Obj object.
How can I receive list of methods which was called on obj without replacing (mocking) and changing obj behavior?

Something like

```
['method2', 'method1', 'method3']
```

Comment: (1) use a testing framework; (2) `[getattr(obj,name)() for name namelist]`

Comment: Yes. I use testing framework, I just call `do_something()`. How can I get list of functions calls of `obj` object?

Comment: Is it within scope to define a generic wrapper class that each object could be wrapped with? Like `obj = Obj()` then `x = Wrapper(obj)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `trace` package. See docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html

From the docs:

```
import sys
import trace

# create a Trace object, telling it what to ignore, and whether to
# do tracing or line-counting or both.
tracer = trace.Trace(
    ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
    trace=0,
    count=1)

# run the new command using the given tracer
tracer.run('main()')

# make a report, placing output in the current directory
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir=".")
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how `trace` can be used to track calls for an individual object? It looks like what is needed might be there but I've never used trace and now I'm curious.

Comment: There is an example in the documentation.

Comment: This doesn't differentiate between different instances of a particular class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic `Wrapper` class which will encapsulate your object and track changes to it.

```
class Obj:
    def method1(self):
        print 'method1'

    def method2(self):
        print 'method2'

    def method3(self):
        print 'method3'

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.calls = []
        self._wrapped = wrapped
    def __getattr__(self, n):
        self.calls.append(n)
        return getattr(self._wrapped, n)
```

By redefining `__getattr__` we cause all attribute accessing on the wrapper to retrieve the attribute in the wrapped object. With the above defined I can do the following:

```
>>> obj = Obj()
>>> x = Wrapper(obj)
>>> x.calls
[]
>>> x.method2()
method 2
>>> x.method1()
method 1
>>> x.method3()
method 3
>>> x.calls
['method2', 'method1', 'method3']
>>> x.method1()
method 1
>>> x.method1()
method 1
>>> x.calls
['method2', 'method1', 'method3', 'method1', 'method1']
```

You can further improve `__getattr__` in `Wrapper` to fit your needs. (record timestamps for the method calls, record output, log to a database, etc.)

Comment: Why would you do this, when you can avoid altering your code at all? You just reimplemented standard functionality.

Comment: Because it fits the needs described by OP, it's highly modular, and it's 7 lines of code...